# WebSocketGremlinRequestEncoder must produce at least one message - janusgraph-dynamodb using withRemote "sideEffect" doesn't work

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, gremlin, titan, janusgraph

When I use gremlin-server connection using gremlin-driver in Java, I am not able to use "sideEffect" of GraphTraversal.

```
graph = EmptyGraph.instance()
cluster = Cluster.open("conf/remote-objects.yaml");
graphTraversalSource = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
```

My query that uses sideEffect looks like:

```
AtomicLong level1 = new AtomicLong(0);    
graphTraversalSource.V().hasLabel("user")
            .has("uuid", "1234")
            .sideEffect(it -> it.get().property("level", level1.getAndIncrement())).emit().repeat(in())
            .until(loops().is(5)).valueMap("uuid", "name", "level");
```

This query used to work when I was using janusgraph-dynamodb-storage-backend as dependency and running gremlin server within Java application and connecting to dyamodb. When i switched to using remote connection to gremlin server running in EC2, i started getting below error message:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: WebSocketGremlinRequestEncoder must produce at least one message., took 3.895 sec
```

If I remove the sideEffect part from the above query, it works fine. I really need to add a custom property during traversal and include that in results without saving it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems. The first problem is that you are trying to remote a lambda in the `sideEffect()` Lambdas can't be serialized to Gremlin bytecode - at least not in the form you've provided. However, you can do this:

```
gremlin> cluster = Cluster.open("conf/remote-objects.yaml")
==>localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster))
==>graphtraversalsource[emptygraph[empty], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('person').as('p').addE('link').to('p')
==>e[1][0-link->0]
gremlin> g.V().sideEffect(Lambda.function("it.get().property('level',1)")).valueMap()
==>[level:[1]]
```

Note that I had to import `import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.function.*` to the console to make that last line work there - That will be fixed for 3.2.7/3.3.0.

So, you could pass your lambda that way, but:

1. I don't think your traversal will work as before because you are referencing a variable local to the client with `level1` - the server is not going to know anything about that.
2. TinkerPop generally recommends that you avoid lambdas.

I don't quite follow what your Gremlin is doing to provide a suggestion on how to resolve this. You do give this hint:

> I really need to add a custom property during traversal and include that in results without saving it in the database.

...but the Gremlin above does write the value of `level1` to the database so I'm not sure of what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the Lambda part, it makes more sense now.

Comment: My data has users with a member type and I am trying to loop through all the users and increment the custom variable "level" when i find a specific type, let's say "admin" - if i only filter them by that type, it stops the loop if one of the users is not "admin" and doesn't go deep into his parents or user that sponsored him - he might not be an admin but his parent could be an admin and i need to be able to get his parent if that's the case. Also, I need to maintain their order that's why i added "level"